# How to create a view using relation from a different table

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two tables `STUDENT` and `RELATION`

`Student`

Roll No        |        Name    |       Marks

---

1                    Peter                 40

2                    Daniel                45

3                  Emma                43

4                    Drake            47

5                   John                   49

`Relation`

Roll No        |        Younger Sibling

---

1                     2

2                    `NULL`

3                  `NULL`

4                     3

5                  `NULL`

Now i want to create a view which shows data like this

Roll No        |        Marks    |       Sibling Marks

---

1                    40                45

2                    45                  0

3                  43                0

4                    47               43

5                   49             0

Assume that there can only be max two siblings in the table and `Roll No` is the primary key for both tables. Relation between siblings is only one way (younger sibling). I am really new to SQL, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  R.RolNo,
  COALESCE(S1.Marks, 0) Marks,
  COALESCE(S2.Marks, 0) SiblingMarks
FROM Relation R
  LEFT JOIN Student S1
    ON R.RolNo = S.RolNo
  LEFT JOIN Student S2
    ON R.YoungerSibling = S2.RolNo
```

Comment: A slight typo `ON R.RolNo = S.RolNo` should be `ON R.RolNo = S1.RolNo`